# Migrating CloudFormation to Terraform aws_lb_target_group_attachment cannot be imported

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation

If we are moving from cloudformation to terraform over a running aws resource, how do we import the alb target attachment to the statefile? terraform does not support it so we have to recreate it? Can anyone suggest a work around? Typical example is ALB with EC2 instances as target_id.
Thanks.